Relation between the parameters of the stable distribution and the stable process.
For the purpose of this question, the stable distribution with parameters $(\alpha, \beta, c, \mu)$ is the distribution with characteristic function,
$$
\phi(z) = \exp\left[iz\mu-|ct|^\alpha\left(1-i\beta\textrm{sgn}(z)\tan\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}\right)\right],
$$
ignoring the special case where $\alpha=1$ which I do not care about.
The stable process is the Lévy process with characteristic triplet $(a, \sigma^2, \nu)$, where the Lévy measure $\nu$ is of the form,
$$
\nu(x) = \frac{A}{x^{\alpha+1}} \mathbb{1}_{x>0} + \frac{B}{|x|^{\alpha+1}} \mathbb{1}_{x<0},
$$
with $\alpha$ being the same as in the stable distribution.
The stable process and stable distribution are related in the sense that the stable distribution is the time-marginal of a stable process.
I would like to know the relation between these two parameterisations. I.e. give the parameters $(\beta, c, \mu)$ for the stable process marginal at time $t=1$, what are the corresponding parameters $(A, B, a, \sigma^2)$ for the stable process that generates this (and vice versa)?
I have tried to find a reference that provides this information but haven't been able to find anything.
I am aware that I could probably compute these relations for myself using the Lévy-Khinchin representation of the stable process and matching coefficients, but my complex analysis is not strong enough to evaluate such integrals.

I ended up finding this relation in Robert Wolpert's Lévy Random Fields notes.
Specifically, Section 2.5.3 states that the $S_\alpha(\beta, \gamma,0)$ distribution has associated Lévy density,
$$
\nu(u)=\gamma c_\alpha \alpha(1+\beta \operatorname{sgn} u)|u|^{-\alpha-1}
$$
where $
c_\alpha:=\frac{1}{\pi} \Gamma(\alpha) \sin \frac{\pi \alpha}{2}
$.
The parameter $\mu$ is associated with the drift term of the Lévy triplet.
